# HTML list, Adding JQuery to cross selected item.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little app that adds items to a list. The items appear with a button next to them, I want to be able to press that button to add a (text-decoration: line-through). I have tried a few different things but nothing seems to work (the Javascript to add items, delete the last item, add classes to the new li elements, etc. All that works fine, my problem is only with the JQuery part, more comments on the code itself).

**HTML**

```
<html>

<body>

<h1> Shopping List </h1>


<button id="add"> Add </button>

<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter Items"> </input>

<button id="remove"> Remove Last </button>


<ul id="list">

</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

**Js/Jq:**

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click', function() {


var check = document.createElement("button");
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var newEl = document.createElement("li");
var newText = document.createTextNode(input);
var buttonText = document.createTextNode("Check");

newEl.className = "liEl";
newEl.appendChild(newText);
newEl.appendChild(check);
check.setAttribute("class", "checked");
check.appendChild(buttonText);


/* Problem starts here */

$("button.checked").on('click', function() {

$('li.liEl').css('text-decoration: line-through');

 /* It should get the button with the class "checked" and on click, make the li elements with class "liEl" to have that css... */

 }
);


var position = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
position.appendChild(newEl);
document.getElementById("input").value = "";



document.getElementById('input').onkeypress = function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
document.getElementById('add').click(); /*  adds an event listener to the submit text, keyCode 13 equals the enter key so when it's pressed it presses the add button. */
}
}
});


 /* Delete last item function: */

  document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var els = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var removeEl = els[els.length - 1]; // <-- fetching last el, If els is an array, it has indices from 0 to els.length - 1. 0 is the first, els.length - 1 is the last index.
  var containerEl = removeEl.parentNode;
  containerEl.removeChild(removeEl);
 });
```

Comment: Your usage of .css() is probably wrong. Start from here: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: That works but weirdly enough, only when there's more than 1 item added to the list (I knew it would cross all of them but no idea why it can't apply the effect when there's only 1 item).

Comment: @Sergi It is because your click function is added before the new element added to DOM. So the function would take effect after you add another item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your jQuery `css` function is wrong, you need to provide two parameter to set css value (see this: [css-property-name-value](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value)).
2. Your selector syntax (`$('li.liEl')`) is not right, it would return all `<li>` element, not the one the clicked button is located. 
   You can use this: `$(this).parent().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');`.
3. Your code contain some bug, the last added button would not trigger the function. It is because your click function is added **before** the new element added to DOM. And it would cause your click function to be triggered multiple time for earlier added button.

Here's the snippet for fixed code. Since you already using jQuery, I change several native java script native element query and event handler whith jquery syntax.

```js
$(function () {
 $("#add").click(function(evt) {
  var input = $('#input').val();
  var check = $('<button class="checked">Check</button>');
  var newEl = $('<li class="liEl"></li>');
  newEl.append(input);
  newEl.append(check);
  
  $(check).click(function(evt) {
   $(this).parent().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
  });
  
  $('#list').append(newEl);
  $('#input').val('');
 });
 
 $('#remove').click(function(evt) {
  var lastEl = $('li.liEl').last();
  lastEl.remove();
 });
 
  $('#input').keypress(function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
   $("#add").click();
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<h1> Shopping List </h1>

<button id="add"> Add </button>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter Items" />
<button id="remove"> Remove Last </button>

<ul id="list"></ul>

</body>
```

Comment: That works flawlessly. I wanted to find the solution to cross items individually afterwards but I will study your code, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use style like `$('li.liEl').css('text-decoration','line-through');`